# API Thumbnail Image returns TypeError: cannot read "url" of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm using NYT API in order to grab the thumbnail/image of the article. But I'm getting `Cannot read property "url" of undefined` error for some of the images. Here's a screenshot from the terminal.

[image: Screenshot]

Since it said that the "url" is undefined, I decided to check (in my function) whether the image source returned `undefined`:

```
var prefix = "http:\/\/static01.nyt.com\/";
var src = prefix + data.multimedia[2].url;
if(!src || src == undefined) { src = "img/img-nyt.png"; }
else { imgSource = src; }
console.log(imgSource);
```

But I'm not sure as to why it still would return undefined because if it is, then the image source should be changed to the `img-nyt.png`.

Here's the sample `JSON` request:

```
"results": [
    {
        "multimedia":[
            {
                "url":"http:\/\/static01.nyt.com\/images\/2016\/01\/20\/us\/20michigan-web\/20michigan-web-thumbStandard.jpg",
                "height":75,
                "width":75,
            },
            {
                "url":"http:\/\/static01.nyt.com\/images\/2016\/01\/20\/us\/20michigan-web\/20michigan-web-thumbLarge.jpg",
                "height":150,
                "width":150,
            },
            {
                "url":"http:\/\/static01.nyt.com\/images\/2016\/01\/20\/us\/20michigan-web\/20michigan-web-articleInline.jpg",
                "height":127,
                "width":190,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And here's my function entire function that gets the values from this `JSON`:

```
// MAKES THE REQUEST AND DISPLAYS THE NEWS BASED ON RESULTS
    function searchArticles(term) {
        viewing.innerHTML = term;
        term = term.replace(/ /g, "+");
        searchURL = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=" + term + "&api-key=" + searchAPI;
        var prefix = "http:\/\/static01.nyt.com\/";
        mainDivToAppendTo.innerHTML = null;
        $.getJSON(searchURL, function(api) {
            var i = 0;
            api.response.docs.forEach(function(data) {
                link = data.web_url;
                var src = prefix + data.multimedia[2].url;
                if(!src || src == undefined) { src = "img/img-nyt.png"; }
                else imgSource = src;
                console.log(imgSource);
                cardTitle = (data.headline.main.length > 43) ? data.headline.main.substring(0, 43) + " .." : data.headline.main;
                postedBy = "In " + data["section_name"];
                i++;
                createCardElements();
            });
            numberOfPosts.innerHTML = i + " results";
        });
    }
```

I just can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this. Maybe I'm just missing something really obvious. Hope I can get some help ..

Here's the entire: sample URL that you could look at:

[http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=donald-trump&api-key=sample-key](http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=donald+trump&api-key=sample-key)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if `data.multimedia[0].url == undefined`
I needed to check if `data.multimedia[0] == undefined`.

I was still getting the error because it was trying to get the url from an undefined object and that did the magic.